# Does "noun + that/which" always need definite article?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article, idiomatic-language

> My view does not apply to **the** relationships that are insincere.
>
> That theory does  not consider **the** relationships in which people are
>   insincere.

Is "the" necessary in the above sentences?

Comment: It depends on what ***you*** want to say. It depends on context, not grammar. That said, apply to "the insincere relationships" or apply to "insincere relationships" is better.

Comment: @Lambie As a reader, what difference do you sense between "my view does not apply to *the* relationships that are insincere" and "my view does not apply to relationships that are insincere"?

Comment: The difference is context. ***the relationships*** suggests there are in a particular context. Apples are red (general statement). The apples are red. [that implies specific apples we are discussing or that there are also other fruit present somewhere.] That is to say, the apples are the market, on the table, etc. Specific ones.